# Java Generics Wildcard capture in a generic method

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I'm studying Java Generics and I'm reading the (very good) book by Naftalin and Wadler, and I got where he's talking about capturing the wildcard in a generic method like the implementation in Collections.reverse :

```
public static <T> void reverse(List<T> list){
    List<T> temp=new ArrayList<>(list);
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        list.set(i,temp.get(list.size()-1-i));
}
```

he says that the method in the Collections class is implemented using a wildcard for simplicity:

```
public static void reverse(List<?> list){
    //code..
}
```

but using the first method body wouldn't work:

```
public static void reverse(List<?> list){
    List<Object> temp=new ArrayList<Object>(list);  //legal
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        list.set(temp.get(list.size()-1-i));        //illegal
}
```

it doesn't work because it attempts to put a Object type element in a list
whose type is unknown(?) and it could be everything extending Object (which is ..well,everything)

so calling the first method from the second should do the trick:

```
 public static void reverse1(List<?> list){
    reverse2(list);
 }

 public static <T> void reverse2(List<T> list){
    List<T> temp=new ArrayList<T>(list);
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        list.set(i,temp.get(list.size()-1-i));
}
```

now,following what happens on method call,for example passing a

```
 List<String> myList
```

1) `List<String> myList` is up-casted to a local variable `String<?> list` (String extending Object, which is the upper bound of the wildcard, makes `List<String>` subtype of `List<?>`)

2) `list` is now passed to `reverse2()` and the parameter T is inferred to be `? extends Object`,now how could I use this as a parameter when I instantiate new `ArrayList<T>()` ??? this is something clearly illegal in Java code, so something else must be happening,please can youtell me what is it??

thanks

Luca

Comment: I don't see where anything here is instantiating an `ArrayList<?>`.  Please surround code fragments (and any code text that needs `<` and `>` to be rendered properly) with back-quotes (a.k.a backticks `\``).  Or you can highlight text and press the `{}` button.

Comment: @rgettman done. I'm passing the type parameter as I call the methods.. I can't understand how can I write the method body passing ? as type argument.

Answer (score 3):

The `T` parameter in `reverse2()` *isn't* inferred to be `? extends Object`, and no instantiation is performed using the wildcard, `?`.

Inference would only occur in a method that calls `reverse2()`. For example, if you call `Collections.emptyList()`, what is the type parameter? In that example, it's unknown, but it can usually be inferred at the calling site:

```
List<String> empty = Collections.emptyList();
```

is inferred to be a call to `Collections.<String>emptyList()` (the explicit form).

In your case, `T` has no restriction, so any type is compatible. If the type variable were declared as `T extends String`, however, the wildcard `?` would be too general to satisfy that restriction, and the call would be illegal.

---

> ok, I got it,so what is it T then? I mean, what does T is inferred to be?

`T` is a type variable in `reverse2()`, and as I explained above, type inference happens in the caller, not the callee, so `T` isn't "inferred" to be anything.

Maybe what you mean is what type shows up in the compiled byte code? In this case, no variables of type `T` are declared; `T` is never used, and no type checking is done. So, consider the following contrived example:

```
final class Reverse {

  static <T extends String> void reverse(List<T> list) {
    List<T> tmp = new ArrayList<>(list);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
      list.set(i, tmp.get(list.size() - 1 - i));
  }

}
```

Now a client that calls that method:

```
final class Test {

  public static void main(String... argv) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    Reverse.reverse(list);
    System.out.println(list);
  }

}
```

Compile these classes together and run `Test`, and you'll get `[C, B, A]`, as expected. Now, *without recompiling `Test`,* change the signature of the `reverse()` method and recompile only the `Reverse` class:

```
static <T extends Integer> void reverse(List<T> list)
```

Re-running `Test` will produce the same result, not a failure!

Now change the implementation of the `reverse()` method, and again, recompile only the `Reverse` class:

```
static <T extends Integer> void reverse(List<T> list) {
  List<T> tmp = new ArrayList<>(list);
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    T el = tmp.get(list.size() - 1 - i);
    list.set(i, el);
  }
}
```

This time, running `Test` will produce the failure you might have expected last time:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

That's because `T` was actually referenced now:

```
T el = tmp.get(list.size() - 1 - i);
```

Into this assignment the compiler will insert a cast to the upper bound of the type parameter, which in this case is `Integer`:

```
T el = (Integer) tmp.get(list.size() - 1 - i);
```

If the type `T` is unrestricted (its upper bound is `Object`) no cast is performed, since it could never fail.

Comment: ok, I got it,so what is it T then? I mean, what does T is inferred to be?

Comment: ok, I understand something but I can't honestly get everything.... I can't understand the inner workings of this Generics stuff...

Comment: @erickson static <T extends Integer> void reverse(List<T> list)
This is giving compile time error

Comment: @shikhar That's just a fragment of code. It won't compile unless it's part of a syntactically valid method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

> `list` is now passed to `reverse2()` and the parameter `T` is inferred to be `? extends Object`, […].

When `reverse2` is called, the wildcard is *captured* to a fresh type variable which is *no longer a wildcard*.* The type of `T` is inferred to be this *captured* type.

The type system ensures that we can only use this feature in a safe manner.

For example, suppose we had a method which accepted *two* lists:

```
static <T> void swap2(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    List<T> temp = new ArrayList<>(list1);
    list1.clear();
    list1.addAll(list2);
    list2.clear();
    list2.addAll(temp);
}
```

If we tried to call this with wildcard captures:

```
static void swap(List<?> list1, List<?> list2) {
    swap2(list1, list2); // <- doesn't compile
}
```

This will fail to compile, because the compiler knows that it cannot deduce that `list1` and `list2` had the same type before they were passed to `swap`.

`reverse2` is type-safe because it adds elements to the list which were originally in the list to begin with.

---

* Technical proof is [*5.1.10 Capture Conversion*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10):

> If `Ti` is a **wildcard type argument** of the form `?`, then `Si` is a **fresh type variable** […].

Comment: I don't know all this capturing the wildcard stuff and I find it hard to understand since I just started learning generics... 
where can I find documentation that's easy to understand on the subject?

Comment: Possibly [Angelika Langer's FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html). Also of course [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). But there's not really a whole lot that I'm aware of that's comprehensive, correct and still easy to understand. (I think StackOverflow is more aiming to be that way but there are some gaps in its knowledge.) The technical reasoning for capture in particular is actually really complicated...I only fully understood it after reading the JLS, which is pretty daunting.

Comment: ok, so I'll put it off to a later time when my knowledge of the language is sound... now I just want to understand what I'm doing in order to write some decent code.
Thanks.